# Getting last folder from a directory using grep or cut

Tags: shell, grep, cut

i just want to have the last word I have tried reverse too still I am not able to get the last word.

```
../init.d/halt
../init.d/killall
../init.d/watchdog
../init.d/iptables
../init.d/network
../init.d/evlogrmt
../init.d/evlog
../init.d/rdisc
../init.d/syslog-ng
../init.d/portmap
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I don't think it is possible to do a one-liner with `cut`, let's propose a `grep` solution:

```
$ grep -oE '[^/]+$' file
halt
killall
watchdog
iptables
network
evlogrmt
evlog
rdisc
syslog-ng
portmap
```

Of course, with `awk` it is pretty simple: `awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file`.

Comment: Thanks :) I did with awk liked the solution that you provided with grep

Comment: +1 Missed that you already listed the awk way. Seems like the simplest way to do it, with reading in a loop being the fastest (at least in bash).

Answer (score 2):

This is what `basename` does:

```
$ xargs -I% basename % < file                                                  
halt
killall
watchdog
iptables
network
evlogrmt
evlog
rdisc
syslog-ng
portmap
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` version

```
$ awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' file
halt
killall
watchdog
iptables
network
evlogrmt
evlog
rdisc
syslog-ng
portmap
```

Another option (bash specific)

```
$ while read line; do echo "${line##*/}"; done < file
halt
killall
watchdog
iptables
network
evlogrmt
evlog
rdisc
syslog-ng
portmap
```

Comment: So both of us couldn't resist posting the `awk` way :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `basename`:

```
$ basename ../init.d/portmap
```

which returns:

```
portmap
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer basename and AWK

but you can also do it using sed, delete everything before / (including /) :

```
sed 's/.*\///'
```

To avoid the backslash, you can run sed in this way:

```
sed 's@.*/@@' file
```

or you can print anything after the last /

```
sed -r 's@.*/(.*)@\1@'
```